# count variable is not being incremented Java

Tags: java

I am trying to follow the book which we are given at the University but count variable is not being incremented despite condition is true ... What am I missing here would like to mention I am new to Java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] list = new int [] {1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 14};

    int count = 0;  
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length -1; i ++){
            if(list[i] == list[i+1])
                count ++; 

    }
}
```

Comment: Under which conditions should it be incremented? Are those conditions met?

Comment: because `if(list[i] == list[i+1])` will never be true based on your array.

Comment: Please use `System.out.print()` to print out the values of `list[i]` and `list[i+1]`. This could have easily been debug just by doing `System.out.println(list[i] + " - " + list[i + 1]);` before your if statement. Or even doing `System.out.println(list[i] == list[i + 1]);` before the statement. What made you think the condition was true? Did you even test it? EDIT: Saw you mentioned you were new to Java. The code I presented (println()) cause be used for easy debugging. Become familiar with it.

Comment: I would also like to point out, this question does not deserve an upvote. He assumed the condition was true without any evidence. A better question would be `How can I check if a condition is true`. Please don't encourage faults like this. I'm not trying to be mean, but upvoting attracts attention, and a simple question like this doesn't need much attention. Don't upvote just because you see a downvote (trying to even it out). Upvote if its a good question that will not only help others out if answered, but will contribute knowledge to the community in some way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(list[i] == list[i+1])` will always be false. Look at the list; there are no two adjacent values that are equal to each other, which is what your `if` is testing. So `count` will always stay 0.

Answer (score 3):

count++; is part of the if wich is always false

your code is equal to  :

```
        if(list[i] == list[i+1]){

            count ++; 
        }
```

list[i] is always different to list[i+1] 1!=3 3!=4 4!=5 .....

if you want to count you have to put count++ outside the is. And i recommend to always put bracket to if and while to avoid this type of mistake